# How do I concatenate two values in Twig to create one value?

Tags: api, twig

I have a Twig short code that takes values from an API and I just want to change this:

```
"latitude":"latitude", "longitude":"longitude",
```

to this:

```
"coordinates":"latitude" ~ "longitude",
```

So that the latitude and longitude (two fields) become one field containing the coordinates that can then be selected for a map.

How can I do that?

Comment: For us to point out how to rewrite your twig code, you would need to actually show it.

Comment: Also what do you mean with `twig shortcode`?

Comment: I'm not used to the terminology.  I guess I meant code, not schortcode.

Here is the code suggested by the plugin developer "mapcoordinates":"mapcoordinates: {{latitude}}, {{longitude}}"

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to add a new key to an existing hash, then you can use the [`merge`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/merge.html) filter.

Given:

```
{% set coord = {"latitude": 40.708780, "longitude": -74.006740} %} 
{% set coord = coord | merge({"coordinates": coord.latitude ~ ' ' ~ coord.longitude}) %}

latitude: {{ coord.latitude }}
longitude: {{ coord.longitude }}
coordinates: {{ coord.coordinates }}
```

This prints:

```
latitude: 40.708780
longitude: -74.006740
coordinates: 40.708780 -74.006740
```

<sup>*Testable here: https://twigfiddle.com/vvla92*</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  Here is the code suggested by the plugin developer

"mapcoordinates":"mapcoordinates: {{latitude}}, {{longitude}}"

I've tried this but with no success so far.  The slug is matched to a custom field in a custom post in WP.  If I use latitude and longitude on their own it works indiivdually, so the process works but not when I try to combine the two.

"latitude":"latitude", "longitude":"longitude" - both work

Answer (score 0):

The answer is `"mapcoordinates":"{{latitude}}, {{longitude}}"`

Simple as that but I had to ask the plugin supplier to confirm it.